# VB.net Windows form (Working with Access Database) displaying a selected combobox item in a textbox

Tags: vb.net

Hello All this is somewhat urgent as this assignment is due Sunday 11/12 at midnight

I have attached what I need help with it is selecting a combobox item then getting the data to display in the textboxes below

I really don't know how to approach it I double clicked the combobox and this is what I started with to try to just get the ID to display. I haven't attempted anything else. I commented out what I tried because it didn't work.

```
Public Class AppointmentsForm
    Private aAppointments As New Appointments

    'Instance of customers
    Private aCustomers As New Customers


    Private Sub AppointmentsForm_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'Combobox must always have a DataSource, Display Member, and Value Member
        'Load the ComboBox with customer name

        cboCustomer.DataSource = aCustomers.Items
        cboCustomer.DisplayMember = "CustName"
        cboCustomer.ValueMember = "CustId"
        cboCustomer.SelectedIndex = -1   'no items selected


        ' load the datagridview
        ApptDataGridView.DataSource = aAppointments.Items

        'do not show TypeID

        ApptDataGridView.Columns(1).Visible = False
        '.Columns(1) TypeID has index of 1 as it is Column 2 in the data sources

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnDelete_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDelete.Click
        'make sure that a record is selected first
        If ApptDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim apptid As Integer
            apptid = ApptDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value

            'Delete selected record by calling the delte function
            aAppointments.Delete(apptid)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnEdit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnEdit.Click
        'make sure row is selected get that row from the table ..... need to find by ID
        'This is a query which you will create in the class
        'Transfer information from that row to the form, display the form
        If ApptDataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            modAppointmentsForm.ApptID = ApptDataGridView.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value
            modAppointmentsForm.ShowDialog()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

HERE IS THE CLASS FOR APPOINTMENTS:

Public Class Appointments

```
Public adapter As New CompanyDataSetTableAdapters.SalesStaffTableAdapter

'error variable
Public Shared Property LastError As String

Public ReadOnly Property Items() As DataTable
    Get
        Dim table As DataTable = adapter.GetData
        'sorted by Appointment id
        table.DefaultView.Sort = "ID"
        Return table
    End Get
End Property

'create a function to combine date and time
Public Shared Function CombinedDateTime(aDate As DateTime, aTime As DateTime) As DateTime
    'declare timespan variable
    Dim tsDate As New TimeSpan(aTime.Hour, aTime.Minute, 0)
    Return aDate.Add(tsDate)

End Function
```

HERE IS THE CLASS FOR CUSTOMERS:

Public Class Customers

```
'create a object variable (tableadapter)
'this will be used to creat instances of this class in the form

Private adapter As New CompanyDataSetTableAdapters.SalesStaffTableAdapter

'property to return a table using the GetData method
Public ReadOnly Property Items() As DataTable
    Get
        Dim table As DataTable = adapter.GetData
        table.DefaultView.Sort = "First_Name"
        Return table
    End Get
End Property

'create a function to filter the customers by custid
Public Function GetByCustomerId(custid As Short) As DataTable
    Dim table As DataTable = adapter.GetData 'entire table
    'filter to get desired row(s)
    table.DefaultView.RowFilter = " ID = " & custid
    Return table

End Function
```

End Class

HERE IS THE CODE FOR THE FORM WITH THE COMBOBOX AND THE TEXTBOX'S SUCH AS ID, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME, ETC. THAT NEED TO HAVE THE DATA DISPLAYED WHEN THE COMBOBOX ITEM IS SELECTED. AGAIN THE ID IS DISPLAYING WHEN I WRITE: IDTextBox.Text = SalesStaffComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString 
BUT IF I DO THE SAME FOR THE OTHER TEXT BOXES (LastName.Text = SalesStaffComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString   ***_*____** FirstName.Text = SalesStaffComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString )  THE ID NUMBER IS DISPLAYED IN THEM AS WELL.

Public Class frmUpdateSalary
    'instances of the required classes
    Private aCustomers As New Customers
    Private aAppointments As New Appointments

```
Private Sub btnCancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub


Private Sub frmUpdateSalary_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    SalesStaffComboBox.DataSource = aCustomers.Items
    SalesStaffComboBox.DisplayMember = "First_Name"
     SalesStaffComboBox.ValueMember = "ID"


End Sub

Private Sub SalesStaffComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SalesStaffComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged
    'fill the textboxes
    'Populate ID textbox with selected customer


    IDTextBox.Text = SalesStaffComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString



    End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what are you asking. Does the data get displayed in cboCustomer?

Answer (score 0):

To select a value form a combobox, listbox or dropdownlist.

```
 If cmbBox.selectedIndex <> -1 Then
     comboIndex = cmbBox.selectedIndex
 End Else

 cmbBox.Items.removeAt(x)
```

to remove the item at the selected index

```
 If cmbBox.selectedIndex <> -1 Then
     comboItem= cmbBox.SelectedItem()
```

Without VS10 to check if those are the correct method names or caps But its essentially it

Comment: Ok well, in your object Customers, can you just provoke the fields id and name? like comboSelectedItem.Name, or comboSelectedItem.ID ?

Answer (score 0):

Your combobox has two data variables for each item, the value and the display.
So for each customer you have the name and his ID (You don't specify if it is the last or the first name).
If in its textbox you say:

```
txtID.Text=cbo.SelectedValue.ToString
txtLastName.Text=cbo.SelectedValue.ToString
txtFirstName.Text=cbo.SelectedValue.ToString
```

You will get the same result for each textbox, since the left side is always the same.
If in your Combobox the Display Value is a combination of LastName and FirstName you can have:

```
txtID.Text=cbo.SelectedValue.ToString
txtName.Text=cbo.SelectedText.ToString
```

I am writing without visual studio so, sorry if I have any minor errors

You don't explain what is  aCustomers but I imagine that the whole information for the  customers are there. So you can retrieve the data with the id that you already have.
If you give as more info we can help.

Comment: Could you please show as the code that you populate the aCustomers and the code for the textboxes. We need to understand what you have in aCustomers and what you sending as values to textboxes

Comment: It is better if you add code to edit your question, because like comment it doesn't make sense. You haven't show as the code for the textboxes.
I haven't clear in my head what you are filling the aCustomers.Items.

But in any case you have all the data. SInce you get the id you can find the first and last name. Where are those info stored?

Comment: HaBouF sorry I'm realitvely new to Stack Overflow and VB so I edited the question hopefully with all of the appropriate code for you to see and the all caps is not me yelling sorry. Please help me if you can.

Comment: So after your edit: Since you apply the same value to the textboxes, they will have the same value (the id).So as far as I understand you get all the customers in property Items. So from combobox you have the id for the customer. Now go to the datatable Items and find the customer with that ID. Retrieve the row and then apply the values for the last name and first name to the textboxes.  
If you want only the first name then you can have it from combobox1.SelectedText

Comment: could you give an example on how to do that I get what you are saying as far as getting the same string in each text box now. I just was never taught in our class how to "Retrieve the row and then apply the values for the last name and first name to the textboxes." That is the frustration with this course and why I have difficulty we are homework assignments are soo much different than what we go over in class.